# Does Canonical track Ubuntu usage? If so, how? Are there "official" figures? Where can I find them?

Tags: canonical

I'm curious as to whether Canonical tracks Ubuntu usage, and if so how, whether there are "official" figures and where I can find them.

So, does Canonical track Ubuntu usage?

If so, how?

Are there "official" figures?

Where can I find them?

---

**Note: I'm mostly interested in seeing such figures, if any exists.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple tl;dr answer is No - Canonical does NOT track Ubuntu usage.

That has been recently confirm by no other than [Dustin Kirkland](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2015/12/more-people-use-ubuntu-than-anyone.html) who is part of Canonical's Ubuntu Product and Strategy team.

Dustin goes on to speculate about Ubuntu usage - the only real figures are from third parties like [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=ubuntu&page=1&isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&starCount=0&pullCount=0) by examining pulls from their repo.

Other figures are indirect - so speculate all you like - Dustin claims 1 billion Ubuntu users (both direct and indirect users via a Ubuntu provided service).

Basically - be proud - Ubuntu is used by lots and lots of users - you are not tracked; you belong to a massive and free community.

Comment: That's actually the article that triggered my curiosity in first place (actually mostly the [linked article](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-No-200-Million-Users), which claims "Canonical isn't too forward about accurate Ubuntu user counts, but most indications these days are that Ubuntu installations -- both desktops and servers -- are in the tens of millions"). Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

type privacy in dash, 
[image]select security & privacy,[image][image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVESh.png)[image]check the settings there, you will find what canonical is/can track and you can disable it.

Comment: I changed my mind an rolled back the question to the previous version, since it seems wrong to edit it now and anyway the answer to it should contain the information I was looking for anyway. Thanks for your answer, but I was looking more for figures with statistics, the answer you posted doesn't seem to provide a way to access such figures / statistics.

Comment: answers can be improvised for better formatting and understandability and the same goes for question too, if the heart of question remains the same.

Comment: Indeed. That's why I rolled back the question to the version you and Tung Tran answered, because it seemed wrong to edit it the way I initially did. How do you think the question could be improved? I'm interested in seeing those figures mostly, as long as they are available obviously. Do you think the question is misleading in this sense?

Comment: Also, I forgot to vote on the answer. I've done that now. If you are aware of ways to have a look at such figures, I may accept it as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, starting in 18.04 Ubuntu will send the following to Canonical:

- Which version of Ubuntu you’re installing (including which flavor)
- Whether you have network connectivity
- Hardware stats, including CPU, RAM, GPU, etc
- Your device vendor (e.g., Dell, Lenovo, etc)
- Your country
- How long your install took to complete
- Whether you have autologin enabled
- Your disk layout
- Whether you chose to install third-party codecs
- Whether you chose to download updates during install

However, there will be options available in the installer and system settings to disable these. Canonical also says that they will make most or all of this information public.

[Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/02/ubuntu-data-collection-opt-out)

Answer (score 1):

> So, does Canonical track Ubuntu usage?

Yes, it does.

> If so, how?
>
> Are there "official" figures?
>
> Where can I find them?

You can find the answers at [Privacy Policy](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy) published by Canonical.

Comment: I changed my mind an rolled back the question to the previous version, since it seems wrong to edit it now and anyway the answer to it should contain the information I was looking for anyway. Thanks for your answer, but I was looking more for figures with statistics, the link you posted doesn't seem to contain them.

Comment: Ok no problem then :)

Comment: Also, I forgot to vote on the answer. I've done that now. If you are aware of ways to have a look at such figures, I may accept it as well. :)

Comment: It doesn't. The most accepted question here has the answer of NO.